# Criação de uma variável a partir de outras colunas no R

Tags: r

Olá,

Eu preciso criar uma coluna a partir de outras, mas não consegui entender uma lógica para o código.
Eu possuo 7 colunas de tipos de violência categorizadas em "1 - sim", "2 - nao" e "NA". Gostaria de unir tudo em uma coluna chamada "viol_outros", possuindo a categoria "sim", quando houver "1 - sim" em qualquer uma das outras variáveis, e "não" quando todas as outras variáveis forem "2 - nao"

```
    ## Variáveis existentes que precisam ser agrupadas
dados_viol$viol_tortura
dados_viol$viol_trafico
dados_viol$viol_financeira
dados_viol$viol_negligencia
dados_viol$viol_trab_infan
dados_viol$viol_interv_legal
dados_viol$viol_outros
```

Obrigada!

Comment: Ola @Lays bem vindo ao SOpt, poderia colocar um exemplo reprodutível, você pode usar o comando `dput(head(df, 30))`, onde df é o nome do seu data.frame, ele vai pegar apenas as 30 primeiras linhas. Voce pode colocar o codigo de saida na sua pergunta. acredito que sua pergunta é bem simples de resolver, basta que tenhamos uma noção do seu problema.

Comment: Além do cometário do @wesleysc352, a pergunta não é completamente clara. Se houver um `"1 - sim"` e 6 `"2 - não"` a nova coluna é `"1 - sim"`. Mas e se também houver um `NA`? O que está escrito na pergunta é *"todas as outras variáveis forem "2 - nao""*, ou seja, ou é `"1 - sim"` ou é `"2 - não"`, nunca pode ser `NA`. Certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não são necessários ciclos `for` ou `lapply` o código seguinte cria índices que dizem quantos `"1 - sim"` e quantos `"2 - nao"` há em cada linha e depois atribui os valores pedidos diretamente.

```r
i_nao <- (dados_viol == "2 - nao") |> rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)
i_sim <- (dados_viol == "1 - sim") |> rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)

dados_viol$viol_outros <- NA_character_
dados_viol$viol_outros[i_nao > 0L] <- "não"
dados_viol$viol_outros[i_sim > 0L] <- "sim"

dados_viol |> head(n = 10L)
#>    viol_tortura viol_trafico viol_financeira viol_negligencia viol_trab_infan
#> 1       2 - nao      2 - nao         2 - nao          2 - nao         2 - nao
#> 2       2 - nao      2 - nao         2 - nao          2 - nao            <NA>
#> 3       2 - nao      1 - sim            <NA>          2 - nao         2 - nao
#> 4       2 - nao         <NA>         2 - nao          2 - nao         2 - nao
#> 5          <NA>      2 - nao            <NA>          2 - nao         2 - nao
#> 6          <NA>      2 - nao            <NA>          2 - nao         2 - nao
#> 7          <NA>      2 - nao            <NA>             <NA>         2 - nao
#> 8       2 - nao      2 - nao            <NA>             <NA>         2 - nao
#> 9       2 - nao         <NA>         2 - nao          2 - nao         2 - nao
#> 10      2 - nao      2 - nao         1 - sim             <NA>         1 - sim
#>    viol_interv_legal viol_outros
#> 1            2 - nao         não
#> 2            2 - nao         não
#> 3               <NA>         sim
#> 4            1 - sim         sim
#> 5            2 - nao         não
#> 6               <NA>         não
#> 7            2 - nao         não
#> 8            1 - sim         sim
#> 9            2 - nao         não
#> 10              <NA>         sim
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11</sup>

---

## Dados simulados

```r
cols_viol <- c("viol_tortura", "viol_trafico", "viol_financeira", 
               "viol_negligencia", "viol_trab_infan", "viol_interv_legal")
prob_viol <- c(0.1, 0.7, 0.2)
valores <- c("1 - sim", "2 - nao", NA_character_)

set.seed(2023)
dados_viol <- replicate(30L, sample(valores, length(cols_viol), TRUE, prob = prob_viol)) |>
  t() |>
  as.data.frame() |> 
  setNames(cols_viol)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11</sup>